# How do I make a variable called @phone for a media query?

Tags: css, responsive-design, less, media-queries

I need to make my page responsive for a phone with a max-width of 500px. Normally I'd do `@media screen and (max-width: 500px)`, but they want me to use LESS and create a `@phone` variable that contains the media string. Right now I'm nesting the media query inside of `@phone` like this:

```
@phone {
    @media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    }
}
```

But I'm getting an error that says "unknown at rule at @phone", so presumably that's wrong. Am I at least in the ballpark? What needs to change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this helps

```
@phone: ~"only screen and (max-width:500px)";
@media @phone {
    body {
        font-size: 30px;
    }
}
```

After compiling above code it will result like below

```
@media only screen and (max-width:500px) {
     body {
         font-size: 30px;
    }
}
```

[DEMO](https://leafo.net/lessphp/editor.html#%40phone%3A%20~%22only%20screen%20and%20(max-width%3A500px)%22%3B%0A%40media%20%40phone%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20body%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20font-size%3A%2030px%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D)